# $http request. Response comes to success function even when status code is 401

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

In my Angular app I have a login function. But when I send wrong credentials and response come with status 401: Bad Credentials (there's even response.status = 401) it still goes to success.

So I'm getting $notify "Success login and then html error page in my interceptor. That's confusing. I'm not sure what I've done to create this mess.

```
this.getTokenCustom = function (user) {
    $http.post('/login',
        JSON.stringify({username: user.username, password: user.password}))
        .then(
            function success(response) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                $.notify({message: "Success login"},{type:'success'});
                $state.go('roles');
            },
            function error(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.notify({message: data.data.message},{type:'danger'});
            }
        );
};
```

**UPD**

```
    this.getTokenCustom = function (user) {
    $http.post('/login',
        JSON.stringify({username: user.username, password: user.password}))
        .then(
            function success(response) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                $.notify({message: response.status + " Success login"},{type:'success'});
                $state.go('roles');
            },
            function error(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.notify({message: data.data.message},{type:'danger'});
            }
        );
};
```

[image: screen]

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that if you put `alert(response.status)` inside the `success` handler, you see an alert box pop up that says 401? It seems like that would directly contradict the documentation, which says only 200-299 are considered successful status codes.

Comment: @smarx, I know, but somehow it doesn't work that way anymore. Look at the new function and screenshot :/

Could it be something related to interceptor activity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The likely cause of this is that you may have a custom interceptor that doesn't handle error conditions properly.

This post can point you on the right direction: http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/AngularJS-HTTP-Service-Success-Handler-400-Response-Code-and-Interceptors/

To quote the post:

> When you handle the requestError or the responseError for a interceptor and you wish to pass the error on to the next handler you must use the promise api to reject the message:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
        'requestError': function(rejection) {
            // handle same as below
        },

        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if (canRecover(rejection)) {
                // if you can recover then don't call q.reject()
                // will go to success handlers
                return responseOrNewPromise;
            }

            // !!Important Must use promise api's q.reject()
            // to properly implement this interceptor
            // or the response will go the success handler of the caller
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

A similar [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2609) to yours was reported on Angular's Github [repository](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues) and the issue had to do with a custom interceptor not handling error conditions properly.

Comment: yeah, I've replaced `return $q.reject(rejection);` with `return rejection`, because it gives me `$q.reject is not funtion`. But at least it's not goint to success now, thanks!